# Using UITableView to show matrix kind of data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

[image]

Here is the screen shot from Cruise Finder app, I want to implement this kind of `UITableView` in which every row scrolls horizontally(synchronous) with table view scrolling vertically.
I need to show a calendar for which First row showing Jun 2013 remains at fixed position,
and all other data scrolls in free form.
Every row has a title, which does not scroll horizontally e.g. 'Oceania'

Answer (score 2):

Calendar should not be a part of your `UITableView`. It should be a separate component. May be a UIScrollView with a background image.

You'll have to create a custom UITableViewCell to create this. In your custom UITableViewCell you'll have to create following things :

1. Sections.
2. UILabel which will not scroll and show titles. e.g. 'Oceania'
3. Then a `UIScrollView` inside a `UITableView`. Which will scroll only till your `UILabel`.

Check the below image :

[image]

Comment: I have done this by adding UIScrollView to my UITableViewCell, and manually scrolling all scroll views if one cell's scroll view scrolls! but not getting the free form scroll like the app I have an image from !

Comment: Do you want to scroll all scrollviews when one scroll is scrolled?

Comment: Yes, If I swipe any cell horizontally, all cells should scroll so as the title of column, in this case Jun 2013 remains appropriate for the price.

Comment: I think I understood what you want to achieve. Did you tried playing with UIScrollViewDelegate methods?

Comment: And, Free From Scroll, by this I mean if I swipe my finger on my screen's diagonal, from left top to right bottom, table view and all scroll views should scroll

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.tableView != scrollView){
        int x = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
        int y =[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
        for(int i = 0; i < x ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < y ; j++){
                UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:j]];
                UIScrollView *sc = [[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
                sc.contentOffset = [scrollView contentOffset];
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can add `UIScrollView` in your `UITableViewCell`

```
[cell addSubview:yourScrollView];
```